# What is the difference between BR-IM and BR-C Shimano drum brakes?

Tags: shimano, drum-brakes

To ride in a hilly area, I'd like to replace a weak BR-IM45 front brake with something stronger (e.g. IM70, IM81 or IM85).

I have noticed that Shimano has two different lineups for their drum brakes: BR-IM and BR-C.

What's the difference?

Answer (score 2):

The BR-IM roller brakes are older models that are discontinued. The current models are the BR-C (e.g. [BR-C6000](https://bike.shimano.com/en-US/product/component/nexus-c6000-int8/BR-C6000-F.html)).

From the [Hub roller brake Dealer's Manual](https://si.shimano.com/en/pdfs/dm/HRB001/DM-HRB001-10-ENG.pdf) (dated 05/31/2021), we can see that the BR-IM and BR-C roller brakes target different series of internal gear hubs. The BR-IM are for the INTER-3 and INTER-5 series (3 and 5-speed) and the BR-C are for the INTER-7 and INTER-8 series (7 and 8-speed).

[image]

As a side note, the bigger the model number, the better the braking power and/or the heat dissipation.